# Unable to access Variables outside a ApexRest call

Tags: json, forcetk

I am trying to parse the response data sent by RestResource in my VF page using Javascript.

The JS looks like:

```
var forceTKClient = new forcetk.Client();
    var Resp;
            forceTKClient.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');

            forceTKClient.apexrest(
                '/AD/SampleResponse',
                function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert((data));
                    Resp = data;
                     alert('Out '+Resp);
                },
                function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('ERROR - ' + textStatus+'/'+errorThrown);
                },
                'GET',
                'json',
                null,
                false
            );

     alert('Outside '+Resp);
```

Although I have assigned the variable "Resp" with the data from the rest output, I am unable to read the same outside the function.

ex; The alert('Out '+ Resp) gives proper output.
But, alert('Outside '+Resp) does not. it gives a blank output.

Also the JSON.parser(Resp) throws a error: unexpected token.

Below is my RestResource:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AD/SampleResponse')
global class ADServiceDemo{

    @HttpGET
    global static string getSampleResponse() {

        return'{    "content": {        "result": {            "countryCode": "USA",            "modeUsed": "FASTCOMPLETION",            "preferredLanguage": "DATABASE",            "preferredScript": "POSTAL_ADMIN_PREF",            "processStatus": "Q3",            "countOverflow": true        },        "resultData": [            {                "elementInputStatus": "60000000000000000060",                "elementResultStatus": "F08080808000000000E0",                "elementRelevance": "10101010100000000010",                "mailabilityScore": "2",                "resultPercentage": "100.00",                "cassStatus": "ECA0",                "serpStatus": "ESE0",                "snaStatus": "ESN0",                "supplementaryGBStatus": "EGB0",                "supplementaryUSStatus": "EUS0",                "key": [],                "country": [                    {                        "type": "ISO2",                        "value": "US"                    },                    {                        "type": "ISO3",                        "value": "USA"                    },                    {                        "type": "ISO_NUMBER",                        "value": "840"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_CN",                        "value": "美国"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_DA",                        "value": "AMERIKAS FORENEDE STATER"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_DE",                        "value": "VEREINIGTE STAATEN VON AMERIKA"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_EN",                        "value": "UNITED STATES"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_ES",                        "value": "ESTADOS UNIDOS (LOS)"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_FI",                        "value": "YHDYSVALLAT"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_FR",                        "value": "ÉTATS-UNIS"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_GR",                        "value": "ΗΠΑ"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_HU",                        "value": "EGYESÜLT ÁLLAMOK"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_IT",                        "value": "STATI UNITI D AMERICA"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_JP",                        "value": "アメリカ合衆国"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_KR",                        "value": "미국"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_NL",                        "value": "VERENIGDE STATEN VAN AMERICA (VS)"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_PL",                        "value": "STANY ZJEDNOCZONE AMERYKI"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_PT",                        "value": "ESTADOS UNIDOS DA AMÉRICA (EUA)"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_RU",                        "value": "США"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_SA",                        "value": "الولايات المتحدة"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME_SE",                        "value": "USA"                    }                ],                "supplementaryUS": [],                "locality": [                    {                        "type": "COMPLETE",                        "value": "MOUNTAIN VIEW"                    },                    {                        "type": "NAME",                        "value": "MOUNTAIN VIEW"                    }                ],                "postalCode": [                    {                        "type": "BASE",                        "value": "94043"                    },                    {                        "type": "FORMATTED",                        "value": "94043"                    },                    {                        "type": "UNFORMATTED",                        "value": "94043"                    }                ],                "province": [                    {                        "type": "ABBREVIATION",                        "value": "CA"                    },                    {                        "type": "COUNTRY_STANDARD",                        "value": "CA"                    },                    {                        "type": "EXTENDED",                        "value": "CALIFORNIA"                    }                ],                "subProvince": [],                "street": [                    {                        "type": "COMPLETE",                        "value": "ADA AVE"                    },                    {                        "type": "COMPLETE_WITH_NUMBER",                        "value": "100-299 ADA AVE"                    },                    {                        "type": "POST_DESCRIPTOR",                        "value": "AVE"                    }                ],                "number": [                    {                        "type": "NUMBER",                        "value": "100-299"                    },                    {                        "type": "COMPLETE",                        "value": "100-299"                    }                ],                "building": [],                "subBuilding": [],                "deliveryService": [],                "organization": [],                "contact": [],                "residue": [],                "recipientLines": [],                "deliveryAddressLine": [                    "100-299 ADA AVE"                ],                "countrySpecificLocalityLine": [                    "MOUNTAIN VIEW CA 94043"                ],                "formattedAddressLine": [                    "100-299 ADA AVE",                    "MOUNTAIN VIEW CA 94043"                ],                "completeAddress": "100-299 ADA AVE\r\nMOUNTAIN VIEW CA 94043"            }        ]    }}';
    }
}
```

Need inputs on why I cannot refer the response data outside the function and why the JSON.parser giving a error as "Unexpected Token"

Many thanks in advance!!

-Prashant

Comment: I would imagine that Resp inside the function yields a value because its invoked by the callback function when the async javascript invocation finishes. The one in the main body executes on load, when Resp doesn't have a value yet.

Comment: Ok. how would I refer the response outside, I want to parse the response using JSON parser.

Comment: I would try invoking Json parsing from within the callback method, i.e. inside the function?

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't seem to work is this:
The request done is an ajax request and that takes a while. The javascript does not wait for this request to finish and therefore alerts Resp before Resp is set.
So this is actually expected behaviour.

Comment: In other words, it *will* be visible in that scope, but not until the call completes. Another function in the same scope could be called to process the response when it's available (thus called a callback).